# Joomla Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, http-status-code-404

From administrator panel I can't find my plugin css or js file. In console log it's showing :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)

Now when I access this file from console login the browser showing me following message :

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access /plugins/system/helix3/assets/css/bootstrap.css on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Can you guys tell me how can I solve this problem. For this error my plugin is not correctly displaying :(

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There is little information you give about your problem, but I will try to help you the same. I had a similar problem and with some research I was able to figure out what my problem was.

First check if file exist /plugins/system/helix3/assets/css/bootstrap.css

Second check the access permissions of your /plugins/system/helix3/assets/css/bootstrap.css in joomla and in the folder permission.

Third check if the css you are using does not need anything else to work. Example in mine was a problem with a plugin for firefox.

Sorry for my English but this is not my native language.